# How to tell a famous professor emeritus that I no longer want him in my dissertation committee?

Tags: thesis-committee

A little background about the situation. I am a third year PhD student in the US and in addition to that I work part time with a famous professor emeritus in my field. He has been overly pushy with being included in my dissertation committee. I honestly don’t think he can add too much and I already gathered my committee. The problem is when I communicated that to him. He wasn’t too pleased. He went with talking again and again of why he thinks he is a good fit, what he brings to the table. He just doesn’t want to respect my decision. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a very strange situation. Why do you care whether he’s on your committee, and why does he? Most of the time being a non-directing committee member is not a very significant task one way or the other. I’d consider very seriously whether you really want to offend a senior member of your field this way, regardless.

Answer (score 8):

If you really want to do this, I suggest that it be your primary supervisor that handles it. But, I seriously think you are making a mistake. You would be far better off cultivating his interest in your work.

You don't describe any improper behavior from this person, such as demanding authorship when it isn't warranted. There are some red flags but some of us old folks can still manage to think and contribute. I'm about to finish 8 decades on this soil and have just recently published some books (plural). He probably has a lot of perspective in your field that you don't.

I suggest, pretty strongly, that you rethink this.